# Durability of a Yate ATS targets

Tags: gear, archery

I may want to get a Yate ATS target. However, I'm a little bit concerned that they don't last very long. Do we know approximately how many arrows the material stops before they fly through?

Comment: That sounds more like a question for the manufactures.